# Why is .tweenTo() not definer for a type double?

Tags: flutter

I have a simple app that is rending a `ListView` of items with a `gestureDetector`. What I want to achieve is that when the page is loaded on the app, the Items appear with a FadeIn effect so it shows the first item, then the second, and so on. (with a smooth effect).

I have the following code:

```
enum _AniProps { opacity, translateX }

class FadeIn extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeIn(this.delay, this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTween<_AniProps>()
      ..add(_AniProps.opacity, 0.0.tweenTo(1.0))
      ..add(_AniProps.translateX, 130.0.tweenTo(0.0));

    return PlayAnimation<MultiTweenValues<_AniProps>>(
      delay: (300 * delay).round().milliseconds,
      duration: 500.milliseconds,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child, value) => Opacity(
        opacity: value.get(_AniProps.opacity),
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(value.get(_AniProps.translateX), 0),
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I am wrapping each ListItems with this FadeIn widget, each with a different delay.

Ex:

> FadeIn(1.0, GestureDector(..........)),

The error that I get is the following:

```
"lib/FadeIn.dart:17:36: Error: The method 'tweenTo' isn't defined for the class 'double'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'tweenTo'.
      ..add(_AniProps.opacity, 0.0.tweenTo(1.0))"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing a similar issue.  I couldn't figure out why 'tweenTo' wasn't defined, but try: `Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)` and `Tween(begin: 130.0, end: 0.0)` instead, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

here: https://pub.dev/packages/supercharged

source:

````dart
part of supercharged;

/// Supercharged Flutter extensions on [double] numbers.
extension DoubleSCF on double {
  /// Returns a [Tween<double>] from [this] value to the given [end] value
  ///
  /// Example:
  /// ```dart
  /// 100.0.tweenTo(200.0) // Tween(begin: 100.0, end: 200.0);
  /// ```
  Tween<double> tweenTo(double end) {
    return Tween<double>(begin: this, end: end);
  }
}
````